# Standalone atmega328

Tags: atmega328

I have a transistor tester with 16x2 LCD running a plug-in at328 with an 8Mhz xtal. I would like to use this hardware for another purpose.

My first idea was to replace the crystal with a 16Mhz one, write a program on my Uno and swap the AT328.

Is this the only way? I also have an USB adapter. Reading/saving the code now on it is of secondary interest.

Comment: Does the transistor tester have an ICSP header?

Comment: To be able to program the chip, by plugging it in the socket of an UNO, it should have the Arduino bootloader. Which is most likely not the case. You can however use the uno running the Arduino-as-ISP sketch to program the bare atmega328.

Comment: Why replace the crystal? Just add or find a 8MHz entry.

Comment: there's a "hack" for the IDE that lets you run one without a crystal at 8MHz...